# How do I get one App Engine Project to query a different App Engine's Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have two App Engine projects.  One collects data into the datastore and does some other things.  The other is just to report on the datastore collections from the first App Engine.  I am writing these programs in Java. I appreciate assistance to how I can make the query work across the two GAE projects.

Comment: Why not simply use two modules within the same project?

Comment: I am using Eclipse and am not sure how to do that.  I know how to add modules in Android Studio, but I want to use Google Web Toolkit, so I'm using Eclipse to develop.

Comment: I also use GWT, and modules is the most logical - and simple - solution. You will have to write much more code than necessary if you try to use two different projects, and you will not be able to take advantage of many of App Engines services like Tasks and Memcache since they all work within a single app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options to access one app's datastore from another:

1. As suggested in the comments you can use **Modules** to combine the two apps into one. Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/
2. You can use `remote_api` to connect one app's datastore from another. Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi
3. You can write your own simple REST API that will server one app the data from its own datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Much has changed since 2014. Today you just can use the
[Google cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java) to for Java to access any Projects Datastore.